# Comparing objects and assigning the right value

Tags: java, object

Hello I am trying to compare the balance of two checking account objects for my class but I've run into a few problems.

```
 public int compareTo(Object other) {
  int otherBalance = 0;
  other = (Bankable) other;
  otherBalance = this.getBalance();
  if (otherBalance > getBalance()) {
     return otherBalance - getBalance();
  }
  else if (otherBalance < getBalance()) {
     return getBalance() - otherBalance;
  }
  else
     return 0;
```

}

The code above has a logic error such that otherBalance is equal to the wrong object's balance. This results in calls to this method always returning 0.

I've tried to correct this mistake by setting otherBalance = other.getBalance(); however this returns the compiler error cannot find symbol. If you could explain why that is I would appreciate it.

Comment: public int getBalance() {
      return balance;
   }

Comment: `other = (Bankable) other;` does not help you because the variable `other` is still of type `Object`. Create a `Bankable` variable instead.

Comment: Looks like a typo - you set `otherBalance` to `this.getBalance()` when you probably want to set `otherBalance` to `other.getBalance()`

Comment: Bankable otherBank = (Bankable)other;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `other = (Bankable) other;` with `Bankable bankable = (Bankable) other;` and `otherBalance = this.getBalance();`with `otherBalance = bankable.getBalance();`.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
other = (Bankable) other;
```

doesn't help you because the variable `other` is still of type `Object`, so you still can't call `Bankable` methods using it.

Create a `Bankable` variable instead.

```
Bankable that = (Bankable) other;
```

then you can call

```
int otherBalance = that.getBalance();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a couple issues:

- `other = (Bankable) other` does nothing, since `other` is always an `Object` type. Try creating a `Bankable` object that has `getBalance`:

  `Bankable otherBankable = (Bankable) other;`
- Once you have that you can fix the other issue, where you set `otherBalance` to `this.getBalance()`. It should be set to `otherBankable.getBalance()` instead.

Another solution that doesn't involve creating another object variable is to just cast when you want to get the balance:

```
otherBalance = ((Bankable) other).getBalance();
```

Answer (score 0):

The "other" parameter for the compareTo method should be Bankable, not Object:

```
public int compareTo(Bankable other) { ... }
```

For this to work, your `Bankable` class should implement the `Comparable<Bankable>` interface - it sounds like you you may be missing the type parameter `<Bankable>` or you would be getting a different error. The Bankable class declaration should look like this:

```
class Bankable implements Comparable<Bankable>
```

Finally, with the way you have implemented `compareTo`, it can only return 0 or a positive number. It must be possible for `compareTo` to return *negative* numbers - that's how it can tell you that the current "this" object should come before the "other" object. A correct and compact way to implement `compareTo` is:

```
public int compareTo(Bankable other) {
    return Integer.compare(this.getBalance(), other.getBalance());
}
```